# What is wrong with this javascript syntax

Tags: javascript, syntax

I am not used to javascript, I still tried but keep on getting syntax errors.
I get syntax errors on this line:

```
var valid = ('@mandatoryF' === 'False' && empty) || (val >= @minVal.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) && val <= @maxVal.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

Comment: Variables can not start with `@`.

Comment: should `'@mandatoryF'` not have quotes, same with false and uncapitalized

Comment: All of the above and `ToString` should be `toString`.

Comment: @Roland probably covered your issue, but in the future, if you have a syntax error, include the error message.

Comment: Also, those variables are undefined, otherwise you would have had an error earlier: at the time of their definition.

Comment: Use a linter like jsHint or esLint to help you find syntax issues. Also, not having so much code on a single line helps zero in on the issue.

Comment: Is mandatory a variable or a string? In you case that is a string. This is same for `'False'`. I think you need to start from basics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `@mandatoryF` is a variable, it should *never* be in quotes. Your variables cannot started with `@`. If by `'False'` you mean the boolean `false`, write it as `false`. `.toString()` has a lowercase t. Make sure all your variables are defined before this line.